# Job/Procedure to PL/SQL execution?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, procedure, jobs

I've this PL/SQL and is working correctly also email is sended.

```
BEGIN
  FOR cur_rec IN
        (select JOB, SCHEMA_USER, WHAT from dba_jobs where Broken = 'Y') LOOP
    BEGIN
 SCHEMA2.send_mail(
            p_to        => 'receive@test.com',
            p_from      => 'send@test.com',
            p_subject   => 'JOB Report',
            p_message   => 'Job name is: ' || cur_rec.what,
            p_smtp_host => 'webmail.test.com');       
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I need to schedule that PL/SQL execution every 4 hours, But I don't know how to create a job or a procedure with that code, I've tried a lot but still saying:

> Completed with warnings

Any help to construct the job or/and procedure is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    begin
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name=>'my_job',
   job_type=>'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action=>
'BEGIN
  FOR cur_rec IN
        (select JOB, SCHEMA_USER, WHAT from dba_jobs where Broken = ''Y'') LOOP
    BEGIN
 SCHEMA2.send_mail(
            p_to        => ''receive@test.com'',
            p_from      => ''send@test.com'',
            p_subject   => ''JOB Report'',
            p_message   => ''Job name is: '' || cur_rec.what,
            p_smtp_host => ''webmail.test.com'');       
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;',
   start_date=>sysdate+1, --start tomorrow at this time
   repeat_interval=>'FREQ=HOURLY; INTERVAL=4', --repeat every 4 hours
auto_drop=>false
);
end;
/
```

Review documentation for additional options.. [create job](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#i1000363)

Comment: You have to remember to escape your quotes in the pl/sql. And also don't end it with a slash (/) like you do with a regular pl/sql block. This assumed you wanted to scheduled via the database. If you wanted to schedule via cron, that is a little different.